# XPages: IBM OneUI vs. Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

In the near future, I have to update a bigger XPage application (development time more than three years) now running on a `Domino Server 8.5.3 FP6` to `Domino Server 9`. In this application I am using `IBM OneUIv2.1` but I am unsure if I should use it further. Unfortunately I have no experience with `Bootstrap`, however in one of the last [Extension Library](https://extlib.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/releases/88452B4042BC826386257F4D00780BF7) releases an  essential part of the update was for Bootstrap:

> This release is the sixteenth IBM Notes Domino 9.0.1 version of the
>   XPages Extension Library (ExtLib) to OpenNTF. This release contains a
>   significant Bootstrap upgrade to 3.3.6.

So for me it seems to be the XPages CSS Framework of the future? 
Am I right?

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use oneUI at the day job. There are some very good things about it.  However, I'm trying to get my company and all my personal work migrated to Bootstrap.  OneUI is not really responsive. Even if that's not a big issue for you the biggest reason to avoid oneUI is the lack of documentation and materials for it.  There actually is documentation for oneUI But nothing like Bootstrap - the most popular framework going as far as I know.  Heck right here on StackOverFlow over 59,000 questions have been asked on Bootstrap.  There's tons of resources like bootsnipp.com.  In my opinion it's almost a no brainer that Bootstrap should be used over oneUI if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks, documentation and community are essential parts of a successful framework or api, therefore I think I will use bootstrap in the future.

Comment: the oneUI components definition is minimal and static http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/components/overview.htm

Answer (score 7):

As long as IBM won't deliver us the new "Verse" UI (which I'd refer to as OneUI Next) I'd prefer the Bootstrap UI as it is responsive. I wouldn't say that it's IBM's future UI framework as departments seem to develop indepently IMHO. The Ireland guys are proclaiming Bootstrap but the IBM Design team propagate their own styles. As always: not a straight strategy here.
But when it comes to application modernization I'd prefer Bootstrap. The next iteration will include Bootstrap 4, too (the final version).
Anyway, using Bootstrap instead of OneUI will deliver more straight and simplified CSS classes other than the "LotusUI" stuff in OneUI.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you (as always) there is no straight forward strategy!

Comment: Oliver let me demo you a Verse UI completely build in bootstrap - not rocket science, but rows and cols nested. Verse on premises actually might be bootstrap based

Comment: Stephan, I asked some IBMer at the end of 2014 if and when we will get the new OneUI that Verse uses. The answer was: "maybe". Still we don't have an updated version so every developer took another approach. I am pretty sure you can "re-design" the Verse UI with Bootstrap or Foundation or whatever, but an "out-of-the-box" version would do better for most developers using the tools they have.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I agree you are right. IBM is staying in front of the curve in supporting Bootstrap for the future. I don't believe that they are investing any more resources in OneUI at this point in time. (Good news, IMO)

On the surface, your question appears opinion based, but really you need to be concerned with the level of support/investment by the IBM XPages team.

If you haven't view it already, I would recommend the TLCC webinar given this month (Feb 2016) by Brian Gleeson and Martin Donnelly on Responsive Design using Bootstrap with XPages.  The team is being extremely proactive in preparing to support Bootstrap 4 which isn't even released yet.

This is the link to the webinar which is very well done:  https://youtu.be/0ylbKHyiFyY

Answer (score 2):

a big advantage with Bootstrap in comparison with oneUI is that there are many sites where snippets for controls / layouts / panels are being shared.

if you stick close to the oneUI defintion you are limited in your presentation options.

also Bootstrap is targetted against multiple clients (mobil / desktop / large) which oneUI is not. so if that is a requirement I definitely recommend bootstrap above oneUI.

there is a learning curve with Bootstrap but manageable.

with Bootstrap I hardly use dojo anymore and disable it in xpages whenever possible.

there are also limitations with bootstrap, e.g. motion awareness but you can overcome them with plugins. you would probably experience the same limitations with oneUI.

once you go bootstrap, you can't get back (to oneUI).

I have little experience with other front-end frameworks so I can not advice on that.

Comment: I thought that the ExtLib Controls still using dojo, no matter if you are working with oneui or boostrap. How you can then disable dojo?

Comment: some of them indeed do so, but you not always need them =)