# bootstrap in xpages development

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I will go modernize completely the first Domino application of organization. I did some developing xpages . The basic! At last weeks I read very articles about bootstrap in Domino xpages, but i didn´t see where I Start.
Some articles say to use bootstrap with application layout of extlib, other say to use bootsrap only. The question is: What is the best choice ?  Are there choices besides choices cited?

Please, could you to indicate, articles, tutorial to this respect?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/35560886/2065611

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how developing in xpages? I must use the bootstrap extlib? Are there tutorials with bootstrap developing in xpages?

Comment: http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/recorded-xpages-webinars?opendocument

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use contemporary tools and mainly focus on using XPages Extlib REST controls to read and write JSON. The approach is outlined [in this post](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2015/10/domino-grunt-json-and-yeoman.html).

It allows you complete freedom in your tool selection and hedges the bets on what is happening on the backend

Comment: I recommend a similar approach with XPages Extlib Java REST control on server side and React.js + Redux + Router + **bootstrap** + webpack + Babel + ES6 + eslint on client side. This way you get high application performance and you are flexible in your dev tools.

Comment: In my opinion, if using the ExtLib, the best practice option for the `service` property in my opinion is the xe:customRestService. However, it looks like it was added after the XPages Extension Library book was published. You will need to code via SSJS or use the `serviceBean` property to map to a Java bean to replace the `doGet`, `doPost` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! If I understand, almost all the xpages components will not be used in developing. Are there a way to use these components with bootstrap? The technics proposed, basicly uses only domino infrastructure. This way the Domino developer community will not use almost nothing than they learned about xpages at last years.

Comment: Just do a quick check: How many AngularJS answers do you get on SO vs Dojo, JSF and XPages questions. You also won't need anything the community learned about LotusScript they learned in the last two decades.

Comment: What is unfortunate , because now the resources used for Domino development are external to the Domino mostly , in addition to all that has been learned so far by Domino developers can throw away . But paradigms are there to be broken . Thank you all.

Comment: You can still - see the article - keep the artefacts inside the NSF. And feel free to accept the answer