# IBM XPages Extension Library

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I would like to update the UI of an XPage application from [OneUI](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/2.1/docPublic/index.htm) to [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) ([see one of my previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560886/xpages-ibm-oneui-vs-bootstrap)) and therefore a have done some investigations concerning [Boostrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) support in the [XPages Extension Library](https://extlib.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library).

Now my general question about the "XPages Extension Library", is this project dead or alive?

### XPages Extension Library on openntf:

https://extlib.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library

*Take a look at the last release date!*

[image]

---

### XPages Extension Library on github:

https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary

[image]

---

Does somebody has another explanation therefore?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtLibX has a Bootstrap 4 experimental release https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20ExtLibX/releases/A8498784907DA6D386257F6200465E8F. That was a release looking for people to use it and give feedback of anything not working. I think most developers have focused on the Bootstrap 3 codestream because Bootstrap 4.0.0 is still not yet in beta (although 99% complete as of today at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/milestones).

If you are committed to 4.0.0, I would recommend using that and giving feedback. The componentised approach of XPages makes so much sense and is what other frameworks tend to use, because if the HTML required changes, it only needs changing once for all instances of the component, rather than everywhere for every instance of the old HTML code.

If you're able to clone the repository and run it against a local server, to be able to troubleshoot in Eclipse, even better. (My recent NotesIn9 on OpenNTF Domino API Starter Servlet gives the setup instructions. Following that video, I imported core ExtLib and was able to build it with any other configuration changes.)

Comment: I am a little bit confused, if this github project is the official development project for the XPages Extension Library then the activities on this project are very low (last update last year) and only one contributor seems not to be a strong community for the future?

Comment: it is not a very active project at all but if you know how to develop your own xpages library then it is a useful starting point if you want to implement your own bootstrap 4 theme, you could use the bootstrap 3 renderers as a starting point. but this would be a huge task and a huge learning curve if you have never done it before.

Comment: The "Contributor" tab is misleading there. All contributions have to go through IBM approval before being incorporated into the core. There is only one IBMer pushing up, which is why there appears to be just one contributor. IBM work probably goes through an internal source control rather than GitHub. Community contributions are through pull requests, and there have been a large number of those, including a number from me. There is a separate project ExtLibX that covers Bootstrap 4, I misunderstood which project you were pointing to. Link added to my answer.